# How to solve Bessel function with rational part?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have a Bessel function in standard form  but with a rational part on the right
$
x^2\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+
x\frac{d y}{d x}+
+(x^2-m^2)y
=ay
$ where $m$ is an integer. 
I have tried to complete the square which could be adjusted by complete the square. However, the result was no longer Bessel function of first kind(i.e. $J_n,Y_n$), as it become rational.

How to solve Bessel function with rational part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the $a$ to the other side.  You get a Bessel equation of non-integer order $\sqrt{m^2+a}$, and its solutions are Bessel functions of that order.

$$ c_1 J_{\sqrt{m^2+a}}(x) + c_2 Y_{\sqrt{m^2+a}}(x) $$